# Update the function run by an event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I am working with Apple Social Sign On and need to run a function after a successful sign on. The function that gets run will change depending on where the user is in the app.

I declare an event listener:

```
   document.addEventListener("AppleIDSignInOnSuccess", (res) =>
     mode === "login"
       ? Apple.onSignInSuccess(res, callbacks, mode)
       : Apple.onVerifySuccess(res, callbacks)
   );
```

The issue I am having is that once this event listener is declared changing the value of the variable `mode` does not change the documents event listener.

Is there a way to update a documents event listeners?

The full class is defined as:

```
export class Apple {
    static init(callbacks, mode) {
        const AppleID = window.AppleID;
        const redirectURIBase = DEV ? "app-dev" : "app";
        const redirectURI = `https://${redirectURIBase}.sandboxx.us/profile`;

        document.addEventListener("AppleIDSignInOnFailure", (err) =>
            Apple.onSignInFailure(err, callbacks)
        );
        document.addEventListener("AppleIDSignInOnSuccess", (res) =>
            mode === "login"
                ? Apple.onSignInSuccess(res, callbacks, mode)
                : Apple.onVerifySuccess(res, callbacks)
        );
        AppleID.auth.init({
            clientId: "com.sandboxx.web",
            scope: "name email",
            redirectURI,
            usePopup: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where is mode defined?

Comment: @Harry I updated my question. mode gets passed in when the button is displayed to the screen. If I navigate from one part of the app with the apple button to another part of the app with the apple button the event listener will not change even if mode changes.

Comment: mode could equal any? So why not callback a code to respond differently?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I am not exactly sure what you mean.  I want the event listener to call a different function depending on what mode is.  The problem is that once the event listener is set it will not change even if mode is changed.

Comment: You have a few issues, when we call for new Apple() and init it; MODE is set then and there so it won't ever change till you re-call init which defeats your class setup.

Comment: The event listeners don't take argument pass-through so you would need to determine mode a different way, overall I'd change the code a bit? That's not saying you can't pass-through but MODE is stuck cause you're not passing this through each time you check.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I do call for a new Apple() and init it in different places but since the event listeners are at the document level they don't change unless the page is refreshed.  For now I can solve the problem by programmatically adding a page refresh after the event listener successfully calls a function.